# rbind() function in R produces NA's in the merged dataframe

Tags: r, merge, rbind

I need some help regarding the rbind function in R. I have the following 2 dataframes.

df1

```
        col1    col2    col3
row1        0       1       0
row2    txt1    txt2    txt3
row3    txtA    txtB    txtC
row4        51      93      83
```

df2

```
        col1    col2    col3
row5    0.732   0.345   0.532
row6    0.453   0.123   0.456
row7    0.656   0.987   0.321
row8    0.432   0.030   0.754
```

I want to merge these 2 dataframes, so I use rbind function to get the following:

```
        col1    col2    col3
row1        0       1       0
row2    txt1    txt2    txt3
row3    txtA    txtB    txtC
row4        51      93      83
row5    0.732   0.345   0.532
row6    0.453   0.123   0.456
row7    0.656   0.987   0.321
row8    0.432   0.030   0.754
```

However, that's not what I get. When I used
merge <- rbind(df1,df2), I get

```
    col1    col2    col3
row1        0       1       0
row2    txt1    txt2    txt3
row3    txtA    txtB    txtC
row4        51      93      83
row5    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
row6    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
row7    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
row8    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
```

So, when I merge these 2 dataframes, I get NA values for the df2. Could anyone help me with getting this right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Always supply [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that one dataframe has only numeric values and the other one has not.

Here is a workaround:

```
> data.frame(t(data.frame(t(df1), t(df2))))
      col1  col2  col3
row1     0     1     0
row2  txt1  txt2  txt3
row3  txtA  txtB  txtC
row4    51    93    83
row5 0.732 0.345 0.532
row6 0.453 0.123 0.456
row7 0.656 0.987 0.321
row8 0.432 0.030 0.754
```

I am not sure how you read in the data, but you could look at the `stringsAsFactors` argument to for example `read.table` or `data.frame`. If you set `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE` you can 
use `rbind`.

To make your example reproducible:

```
> df1 = read.table(header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, text='        col1    col2    col3
+ row1        0       1       0
+ row2    txt1    txt2    txt3
+ row3    txtA    txtB    txtC
+ row4        51      93      83')

> df2 = read.table(header=T, text='        col1    col2    col3
+ row5    0.732   0.345   0.532
+ row6    0.453   0.123   0.456
+ row7    0.656   0.987   0.321
+ row8    0.432   0.030   0.754')

> rbind(df1, df2)
      col1  col2  col3
row1     0     1     0
row2  txt1  txt2  txt3
row3  txtA  txtB  txtC
row4    51    93    83
row5 0.732 0.345 0.532
row6 0.453 0.123 0.456
row7 0.656 0.987 0.321
row8 0.432  0.03 0.754
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is `df1` columns are factor, use `as.is=TRUE` when reading in the data.

Example:

```
#reproducible df1
df1 <- read.table(text="
col1    col2    col3
row1        0       1       0
row2    txt1    txt2    txt3
row3    txtA    txtB    txtC
row4        51      93      83",header=TRUE,as.is=TRUE)

#reproducible df2
df2 <- read.table(text="
col1    col2    col3
row5    0.732   0.345   0.532
row6    0.453   0.123   0.456
row7    0.656   0.987   0.321
row8    0.432   0.030   0.754",header=TRUE)

#result
rbind(df1,df2)

# col1  col2  col3
# row1     0     1     0
# row2  txt1  txt2  txt3
# row3  txtA  txtB  txtC
# row4    51    93    83
# row5 0.732 0.345 0.532
# row6 0.453 0.123 0.456
# row7 0.656 0.987 0.321
# row8 0.432  0.03 0.754
```

Answer (score 1):

`?rbindlist` from library(data.table) seems to work with factor columns as well.

```
 df1 <- read.table(text='col1    col2    col3
 row1        0       1       0
 row2    txt1    txt2    txt3
 row3    txtA    txtB    txtC
 row4        51      93      83',header=T,stringsAsFactors=T)

 df2 <-  read.table(text='col1    col2    col3
 row5    0.732   0.345   0.532
 row6    0.453   0.123   0.456
 row7    0.656   0.987   0.321
 row8    0.432   0.030   0.754',header=T)

 library(data.table)
  rbindlist(list(df1,df2)) #returns factor columns
 #  col1  col2  col3
 #1:     0     1     0
 #2:  txt1  txt2  txt3
 #3:  txtA  txtB  txtC
 #4:    51    93    83
 #5: 0.732 0.345 0.532
 #6: 0.453 0.123 0.456
 #7: 0.656 0.987 0.321
 #8: 0.432  0.03 0.754
```